# Vite is not serving index.html from subdirectories

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have bootstrapped a react-typescript project with vite and made some changes to have multiple pages.

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── about.4ea9bc70.js
│   │   ├── jsx-runtime.2877e684.js
│   │   ├── main.254c5505.js
│   │   └── react.35ef61ed.svg
│   ├── index.html
│   └── reports
│       └── index.html
├── package.json
├── public
│   └── vite.svg
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.tsx
│   ├── reports
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── reports.tsx
│   └── vite-env.d.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.node.json
├── vite.config.ts
└── yarn.lock
```

I can vite http://localhost:5173/ and see my top level `index.html` page.

Hover when I visit http://localhost:5173/reports it doesn't serve `index.html` that is located inside `reports` folder.

If I visit http://localhost:5173/reports/index.html then I can see the desired file.

Why isn't it serving  `reports/index.html` file when I visit `reports/`? How do I make it work that way? I have been searching for hours but didn't find any solution.

Here is my `vite.config.ts`.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { resolve } from 'path'
const root = resolve(__dirname, 'src')
const outDir = resolve(__dirname, 'dist')

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  root,
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(root, 'index.html'),
        about: resolve(root, 'reports', 'index.html'),
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: did you find out?

Comment: @WizardofKneup no :( I'll update here if I find,

Answer (score 1):

I solved issue by using my custom plugin. By default `/reports/` and `/reports` are different routes. Vite was serving same content on `/` and `/reports`. If there is no `/` in end it's not treated as a directory.

In the plugin I check if the route being requested is path to a directory and then check if it's missing the `/` at the end. If it's missing I'll just add a `/` and redirect the request to that path.

vite.config.ts :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { resolve, join } from 'path'
import * as fs from 'fs';
const root = resolve(__dirname, 'src')
const outDir = resolve(__dirname, 'dist')

// plugin
const redirectToDir = ({ root }) => ({
  name: 'redirect-to-dir',
  configureServer(server) {
    server.middlewares.use((req, res, next) => {
      const filePath = join(root, req.url);
      fs.stat(filePath, (err, stats) => {
        if (!err && stats.isDirectory() && !req.url.endsWith('/')) {
          res.statusCode = 300;
          res.setHeader('Location', req.url+"/");
          res.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
          res.end();
          return;
        }
        next();
      });
    })
  },
});

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  root,
  plugins: [react(), redirectToDir({root})],
  build: {
    outDir,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(root, 'index.html'),
      }
    }
  }
})
```

You can get working example at : https://github.com/Omkar76/vite-multipage

---

Default vite server is [senchalabs/connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect). You may want to use express instead  https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html#setting-up-the-dev-server